# Why does Amy say "So needy" in this context?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I watched an episode of Big Bang Theory, here's a recap:

[Subtitle of Big Bang Season 4 , Episode 17](http://www.tvsubtitles.net/subtitle-160557.html)

I don't quite get it when Penny told a joke and then Amy said "So needy." over the phone holding by Sheldon.

Well from ODO, needy means `poor or emotionally insecure`.

I'm not sure if I'm right: `Amy thought Penny is needy because Lenerd left her`?

But from the previous conversation it doesn't sound like so.

Comment: What's OXD? The Oxford English Dictionary is OED and Oxford Dictionaries Online is ODO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amy is accusing Penny of being devastated about Leonard having a new girlfriend. Penny denies that she is.

> Penny: Okay, I’m not upset about Leonard and Priya.
>
> Amy: Your flaring nostrils indicate otherwise.

Then, as the conversation continues and Amy tries to console Sheldon about no longer being the nucleus of the group:

> Amy: I’m not saying that you’re not fun. You’re the most fun person I
>   know.

Penny interjects:

> Penny: A lot of people think I’m fun to be around.

Amy takes this as Penny needing attention and validation that she is important even though Leonard is dating someone else.

> Amy: Don’t be needy, bestie. That’s probably part of what chased
>   Leonard away.

Then Amy and Sheldon continue to discuss how the group is now Leonard-centric:

> If it were a town, it would be Leonardville. If it were an Islamic
>   nation, Leonardstan...

Penny than adds:

> Ooh, I got one. If you guys were a band, you’d be called Leonard and
>   the Leonards.

Amy again takes this as Penny feeling devastated over Leonard having a new girlfriend.

> Amy: So needy.